# Inverse of an element of the group $\mathbb{Z}_n$ under addition $\pmod{n}$

Tags: group-theory

Quick Check:

Find the inverse of the element $13$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{20}$ under addition $\pmod{20}$.

For any $j>0$ in $\mathbb{Z}_n$, the inverse of $j$ is $n-j$. Hence, our inverse element is $7$ since $(13+7) \equiv 0 \mod20.$

This seems pretty straightforward, however the answer in the back of my book says the inverse element is $17$. Is this a typo?

Comment: It's a typo. $13 + 7 = 20\equiv 0\mod 20$.

Comment: No reason for confusion, yes it's a typo :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be a typo and typo is either for "addition" part or in the answer. Because if we consider "multiplication" instead of addition, then yes, $13^{-1}$ is $17$. But for addition, your answer is correct of course.

**EDIT:** A little correction, $\mathbb{Z}_{20}$ under multiplication is *not* even a group so typo must be in the answer. I apologize for not realizing that in the first place.

As Mees de Vries stated on comments, $\mathbb{Z}_{20}^*$ under multiplication can be a valid option for $13^{-1}$ being $17$.

Comment: While that's true, they could have meant "$(\mathbb Z_{20})^*$ under multiplication", and then it might still been a "typo".

Comment: Yes, you are right, $\mathbb{Z}_{20}^*$ is a valid option. I will also write it on the edit part. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Notice that

$$ 13+7  \ \text{mod 20}=0 \ \Rightarrow -13 =7 \ \ in \ \ \mathbb{Z}_{20} $$

Thus $ \ 7 $ is the inverse element of $ 13$ in $ \ \mathbb{Z}_{20} $.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Your answer is correct. 7 will be inverse of 13. 17 can not be inverse of 7 because (17+13) mod20=10 and 10 is not additive identity in our case.(0 is additive identity here)